# ZipArchive creates file, but ZipArchive::close() unable to rename it

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, php-ziparchive

I've looked around, and while the error message I'm getting shows up, this particular problem seems novel.  I have a PHP script constructing a zip file using the ZipArchive library.  The file is actually being created successfully, but when I call `close()` I get the commonly reported ErrorException:

```
ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: No such file or directory
```

The zip file is created successfully, but when I look for it after the exception is thrown it has an extension like `.zip.a04896`.  If I chop off `.a04896` then I can open the file without a problem and it contains the expected content; I assume it's some sort of indicator that the file is still under construction. Since I'm not specifically accessing the zip archive by file name I would assume that would not interfere with the renaming attempt.

I'm running Windows 10, and the code is part of a Laravel 5.3 app.  Here is the code in question:

```
            $zip = new \ZipArchive();
            $zipFile = config( 'app.upload_root' ).'\\downloads\\Interventions_'.$fileTime.".zip";
            if ($zip->open($zipFile, \ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
                throw new \Exception("cannot open <$zipFile>\n");
            }
            foreach ($interventions as $row) {      
                $pdf_name = config( 'app.upload_root' ).'\\uploads\\'.$row->UIC.'_'.sprintf("%010d",$row->id).'.pdf';
                if( file_exists($pdf_name) ){                   
                    $result = $zip->addFile( $pdf_name, $row->UIC.'_'.sprintf("%010d",$row->id).'.pdf' );
                    if ($result == FALSE ){
                        throw new \Exception( $pdf_name.' did not add to ZIP succesfully');
                    }
                }
                else{
                    throw new \Exception( $pdf_name.' does not exist' );
                }
            }
            file_put_contents ( $textFile, $output );
            $result = $zip->addFile($textFile, $textFileName);
            if ($result == FALSE ){
                throw new \Exception( $testFileName.' did not add to ZIP succesfully');
            }
            sleep(1);
            $zip->close();
```

Any suggestions as to what's going wrong here?  Is it possible that under Windows 10 I need different permissions to rename a file than to create it?  Or is that weird extension after `.zip` the problem?

Comment: I suspect that `file_put_contents()` is interfering with `\ZipArchive`. If you need to generate ZIP contents dynamically, you may want to try `ZipArchive::addFromString()`.

Comment: The file_put_contents() call is saving a text file to the `downloads` directory. 
 After it has been saved, it is separately added to the zip file.  The saved text file is getting added just fine, so I'm not sure how the means of its creation could be at fault.

Comment: Despite my incredulity I tried switching to `addFromString()` and it didn't change anything. I'm still getting a valid zip file with all contents and a weird additional suffix on the extension, along with the same error message.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work, but I can't see why it was such a crazy idea. Unexpected file system failures sometimes happen because a given item is held open by another operation (I've had endless problems in the past to rename an Access file on which I've established and closed an ODBC connection).

Comment: I appreciated the suggestion, and you're right, stranger things have happened.  I'm considering looking at other zip libraries for PHP, but I'd prefer to figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is annoying:  the problem has subsequently disappeared, and the zip archives are closing without a hitch.  My development machine has been rebooted since my original posting, so my assumption is that >something< had a lock persisting as Álvaro had suggested.